# How many combinations can be made in the game Sudoku

Tags: probability, puzzle, combinations

I have the game Sudoku. how many combinations can be made by random entering of numbers on the whole such that it makes unique combination in $3\times 3$ grid and $9\times 9$ also.

[image: Tic tac Toe]

Comment: @vadim123 yes. i got the answer from the link given by you where one of them has posted answer http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudoku.pdf

Comment: for the case i know if the sudokus are made of blocks n x n the maximum possible sudokus (higher bound) are   $ ((n^2 )!)^n $